# How to put validation on a dynamic dropdown when inserting in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I'm constructing a survey and I have a textbox that generates dynamic dropdowns based on user input which displays the same data.

This is the script

```
  <script>
           function load_questions(){

                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php??main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


            }

 function checkValues() {
        _values = [];

        $('.form-control-static').each(function() {
            _values.push($(this).val());
            //console.log($(this).val());
        });

        sameValue = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < (_values).length; $i++) {

            for ($w = 0; $w < (_values).length; $w++) {

                if (_values[$i] === _values[$w] && $i != $w) {
                    sameValue = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (sameValue) {
            alert('has the same value .');
            return false;
        }
        alert('there is no the same value');

        //do something .
    }
    </script>
```

This is the insert code when I'm creating the survey

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","imetrics");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $title = $_POST['surveytitle'];
    $catdd = $_POST['catdd'];
    $subcatdd = $_POST['subcatdd'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];
    $occupationtwo = $_POST['occupdd'];
    $relstatus = $_POST['relationshipstatus'];


    $q_num  = $_POST['q_num'];




    $insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `surveyform` (`surveytitle`,`surveycategory`,`surveysubcategory`,`gender`,`age`,`occupation`,`occupation_status`,`status`) VALUES ('$title','$catdd','$subcatdd','$gender','$age','$occupation','$occupationtwo','$relstatus')");
    if(!$insert){
        echo mysqli_errno();
    }
    else{

        $getMaxID = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(survey_id) as maxid FROM surveyform");


        $row_2 = mysqli_fetch_array($getMaxID);
        $survey_id = $row_2[0];
        for( $a = 1; $a <= $q_num; $a++)
        {
            mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO surveyform_questions (  survey_id, question_id) VALUES ('$survey_id', ". $_POST['question_dropdowns'.$a] .")");
            //echo "INSERT INTO surveyform_questions (  survey_id, question_id) VALUES ('$survey_id', ". $_POST['question_dropdowns'.$a] .")";
        }




        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Survey Created!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
}



?>
```

And this is my dropdown code

```
if($question !="" && $cnt!="" && $addQues!="yes" && $main != 1){
    $i = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cnt; $i++)
    {
        $query=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_subcat = $question ");
        echo "<b>Question #". $i."</b>";
        echo "<select id='question_dropdown".$i."' class='form-control-static' name='question_dropdowns".$i."'>";
        echo "<option selected>"; echo "Select"; echo "</option>";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[question_id]'>";
            echo $row["questiontitle"];
            echo "</option>";

        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "<br />";

    }

    echo "<div id='insertQuesHere".$i."'></div>";
    echo "<a href='#add_question' onclick='return addQues();'>Add Question</a>";
}
```

here's my submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="" id="btnSaveSurvey" class="form-control-static" onclick="checkValues();" value="check" />
```

What's the validation code that will prevent me from inserting if the data chosen from the dropdown is the same? For example I generated 2 dropdowns and I chose the same datas from the dropdown, what's the validation code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please call **checkValues** method your submit button click

```
  <input type="submit" name="" id="btnSaveSurvey" class="form-control-static" onclick="checkValues();" value="check" />
```

checkValues method below  :

```
     function checkValues() {
        _values = [];

        $('.form-control-static').each(function() {
            _values.push($(this).val());
            //console.log($(this).val());
        });

        sameValue = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < (_values).length; $i++) {

            for ($w = 0; $w < (_values).length; $w++) {

                if (_values[$i] === _values[$w] && $i != $w) {
                    sameValue = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (sameValue) {
            alert('has the same value .');
            return false;
        }
        alert('there is no the same value');

        //do something .
    }
```

Also , you can see an example [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/rufat_askerov/ev84ks5d/2/)

Comment: Can you be more specific on where I put them? I dont use script that much and all my script I got came from youtube. @rufat askerov

Comment: can you tell me which button or control submit form  ?

Comment: here sir <input id="btnSaveSurvey" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Create Survey"> @Rufat Askerov

Comment: I changed answer , in submit button click please call checkValues method. 
example : https://jsfiddle.net/rufat_askerov/ev84ks5d/2/

Comment: Sir it's still not inserting even though I didn't choose the same data. I edited the comment with your code in it @Rufat Askerov

Comment: But the validation is working though but even though im not choosing the same data it's still triggering the validation that I chose the same value. @rufat Askerov